# Configure Redirection Handler in Cherokee Server 0.99.39

Tags: configuration, redirection, cherokee

I want to move my site from Apache to Cherokee. The install and basic configuration went very smoothly. However, I am having some difficulty with the URL rewriting configuration.

For example, in my current Apache .htaccess file I have the following:

```
RewriteRule ^index.html/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?language=$1
```

Which I add to the Default Rule Redirection Handler in Cherokee as follows:

```
Regular Expression: ^index.html/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
Substitution: /index.php?language=$1
```

When I make a GET request from the browser the response is a 500 error. There is nothing that helps me in the Cherokee logs either (the message is 'The issue seems to be related to your system.').

If anyone has any experience with this please can you share with me? Once I get round this problem I will be clear to update my production environment with Cherokee.

Many thanks in advance.

Darren

Comment: I managed to get this working by brushing up on my regex...

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my default rule handler:

```
  regex = ([^/]+)
  substring = /index.php?language=$1
```